# unable to fetch changes from upstream, says everything up to date, even when its not: git + bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit

I am at a total loss here, need some suggestions to even start investigating.

I am using bitbucket with egit in eclipse. I pushed commit onto the remote, but something went wrong that time( which I am guessing) and I dont see the same change in my local from where I pushed. Then I committed another change after that and I am not able to push it on to remote because there is a change in remote which is not in my local ( as mentioned earlier). So now I try to pull or fetch + merge that change into local to make my workspace up to date. At this point git says not changes in remote to fetch everything is up to date!

So now I cant push my new commit to remote nor am able to fetch the old commit back from remote!

So ya pretty screwed up case. Pls provide some suggetions to at least start looking into it.
Thanks.

EDIT: The error msgs are simple, while pushing the commit It says "push rejected - non fas forward" which means there is commit in the remote which i need to pull. While fetching i get"fetch failed: nothing to fetch, everything is up to date"

Comment: Can you provide us the exact error message etc?

Comment: Have you checked your _local_ commits tree? Maybe you have already fetched everything and tip of remote branches isn't an ancestor of your current `HEAD`?

Comment: Checked it. Its pointing to the latest local commit. As said earlier the last commit on server is missing on my local(still guessing how). The second to last commit is present. I reset my local head to that commit and then try to fetch . fails.